# Python: slice a matrix horizontally

Tags: python, list, matrix, slice

Let's consider those two variables :

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
          [5, 6, 7, 8],
          [9, 10, 11, 12]]

list_of_lengths = [2, 1, 1]
```

I am looking for a method to get this result :

```
result = [[[1, 2],
           [5, 6],
           [9, 10]], [[3],
                      [7],
                      [11]], [[4],
                              [8],
                              [12]]]
```

Indeed, I want three matrix as a result. The j-length of each one is determined by the variable list_of_lentghts.

I have already written a solution that works, but I would like to know if there is a solution more simple. Here is my solution:

```
def cut_matrix(matrix, list_of_lengths):
    result = []
    for a_len in list_of_lengths:
        current_sub_matrix = []
        for a_line in matrix:
            current_new_line = []
            for i in range(0, a_len):
                current_new_line.append(a_line.pop(0))
            current_sub_matrix.append(current_new_line)
        result.append(current_sub_matrix)
    return result
```

Comment: Are you accepting solutions using the `numpy` library? If not, please remove the [tag:numpy] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the column offset `i` and the number of columns `n`, you can use *slicing* to obtain the columns:

```
[row[i:i+n] for row in matrix]
```

to get the slice. So you can simply use:

```
def cut_matrix(matrix, list_of_lengths):
    result = []
    col = 0
    for a_len in list_of_lengths:
        result.append([row[col:col+a_len] for row in matrix])
        col += a_len
    return result
```

It generates:

```
>>> cut_matrix(matrix,list_of_lengths)
[[[1, 2], [5, 6], [9, 10]], [[3], [7], [11]], [[4], [8], [12]]]
```

This will also work faster than using `.pop(0)` since popping from the front is done in *O(n)* (so popping all elements requires *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* whereas slicing all elements is done in *O(n)*). Finally it leaves the original `matrix` intact which is thus more *declarative*.